# Alerta da classe MediaPlayer do Android: Should have subtitle controller already set

Tags: java, android

Depois que atualizei para o Android KitKat (4.4), um objeto da classe `MediaPlayer` do Android gera o seguinte alerta no *LogCat*:

> Should have subtitle controller already set

Conforme explicado [nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166186/android-mediaplayer-warning-should-have-subtitle-controller-already-set) do SO, bastaria chamar o método `setSubtitleAnchor` da classe `MediaPlayer`, conforme o [exemplo](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java#307) fornecido faz, que o alerta sumiria.

Esse alerta não me traz mal algum, não ligo de deixar ele lá, afinal nada de ruim ocorre, sem exceções, sem mensagens visuais para o usuário, mas ainda assim gostaria de eliminá-lo.

Contudo, procurei na [documentação da classe](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) `MediaPlayer`, já considerando o *API Level 19*, e não consegui encontrar o método `setSubtitleAnchor`.

Existe outro modo para fazer com que esse alerta não seja mais gerado pela classe `MediaPlayer`? Ou ainda, como encontrar esse método `setSubtitleAnchor`?

*Ressaltando que minhas instâncias da classe `MediaPlayer` são todas utilizadas para reproduzir apenas áudio, nenhum tipo de vídeo é reproduzido em momento algum.

Comment: Só editei para dar mais uma chance para a pergunta, foi duro achar algo que pudesse ser editado :)

Comment: @bigown Valeu! Eu já meio que desisti disso! Não achei nenhuma solução para isso até hoje, a não ser ignorar o warning! :P

Comment: @bigown mais de um ano já se passou, e só agora consegui responder de forma a sanar minha curiosidade :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, depois de muito tentar, e procurar, a melhor solução que encontrei é ignorar a mensagem por completo, conforme diz [essa resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20149754/3569421) (uma tradução livre/resumo):

> Algum desenvolvedor do Google adicionou suporte a legendas no `VideoView`.
>
> Quando o `MediaPlayer` começa a reproduzir uma música ele verifica se existe um `SubtitleController` e exibe essa mensagem caso não exista, independente da origem ser um áudio ou vídeo.
>
> **Resposta curta**: ignore essa "exceção"

Ainda de acordo com essa resposta, isso ainda está presente no Lollipop, e o único meio de remover esse alerta é utilizando *Reflection* para acessar o método escondido `setSubtitleAnchor` da classe `MediaPlayer`.

No meu caso, prefiro não ter que fazer isso, e como essa mensagem é apenas uma **informação** e não uma exceção/alerta (como o LogCat diz), simplesmente vou ignorar a mensagem para todo o sempre.